# Реализация алгоритма сортировки

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать алгоритм разделения списков. Задается шаг, который будет использоваться для сортировки, затем список должен быть преобразован по первому значению.

К примеру, список [0, 25, 50, 100, 125, 150, 130, 200, 225, 180]
Шаг +-25
В итоге получается список списков [[0, 25], [50], [100, 125], [150, 130], [200, 250, 180]]
А затем он превращается в [0, 0, 50, 100, 100, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200]

Comment: Не понятен принцип поручения первого списка м списков. Почему там нет, к примеру, [25, 50]? А с получается второй список - вообще загадка.

Comment: @strawdog А по моему всё понятно. В подсписок группируются все последующие числа в заданном диапазоне от первого, иначе начинается новый подсписок. А дальше все элементы в каждом подсписке заменяются на первый (опять же в каждом подсписке) и весь список планаризуется. А вот с какого боку здесь сортировка - это вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
lst = [0, 25, 50, 100, 125, 150, 130, 200, 225, 180]
delta = 25

# группируем
groups = [[lst[0]]]
for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    if groups[-1][0] - delta <= lst[i] <= groups[-1][0] + delta:
        groups[-1].append(lst[i])
    else:
        groups.append([lst[i]])
print(groups)

# плющим
res = []
for el in groups:
    res += [el[0]]*len(el)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно проще сделать, сразу собирая список:

```
lst = [0, 25, 50, 100, 125, 150, 130, 200, 225, 180]
delta = 25

lst_new = [lst[0], ]
for _ in lst[1:]:
    if abs(_ - lst_new[-1]) <= delta:
        lst_new.append(lst_new[-1])
    else:
        lst_new.append(_)
```